How many different paths can a king take from $A$ to $B$ on a chessboard using exactly $7$ moves?
Question: In a single move , a King $K$ is allowed to move to any of the squares touching the square it is on, including diagonals, as indicated in the figure. The number of different paths using exactly seven moves to go from $A$ to $B$ is ___________.
The figure below shows the $8$ possible moves for the King:

In a single move, the King can move to any of the adjacent squares, including diagonals. This gives the King up to $8$ possible moves from any position on the grid.
My Approach:
I started using combinatorial methods to try to calculate the number of paths the King could take. I considered:

Counting Possible Moves:
Since the King can move in $8$ directions, I initially thought that the total number of possible moves would be $8^7$, but this clearly doesn't account for the constraints of the grid or the need to end at point $B$.


Could someone help me find the correct number of paths or guide me on how to proceed with solving this problem?

Hint:  Well, each move must take the $K$ one step to the right.  Of course, the $K$ can also go up or down (when such moves are possible) as often as he likes.  Thus you  only need to consider the up and down moves, for which see the Dyck word expression for the Catalan Numbers

While lulu's comment already addresses the general case, I would like to highlight something for the specific case in OP. Starting from A as in the figure, you may calculate the number of minimum steps required to move to B if the first step is North or Northeast.

Begin with filling the second column with ones in the fields the king can reach in 1 move. To fill the next column , sum up the numbers in the neighboured cells of the column one left of the current column. This way you can easily determine the final answer without any combinatorical computations.

How could I only consider the up and down moves?

Has the board only $4$ rows , or does it continue ? Is it the standard chess board ?

Its not standard, its only 4 rows, as the figure shows.

@Peter That's actually irrelevant.  It would take at least $4$ moves to reach a fifth row and then $4$ more moves to return to the first row.  Since you're only allowed a total of $7$ moves, that's not possible.

@RobertShore I noticed this as well, but was nevertheless confused by the arrows in the picture.

@randomuser Did you try to apply my method ? Does it coincide with the combinatorical method ?

@lulu Catalan numbers count paths where each step is $(1,1)$ or $(1,-1)$, but this problem also allows $(1,0)$. A better hint would be to look at Motzkin numbers.

@MikeEarnest it's just a sum of Catalan numbers,  no? Any gap is taken up by horizontal moves.

Consider the ways to move right :

Purple lines indicate moving from $A$ to $2^{nd}$ column , which is the first move : there will be $1$ way to move to each Square.
Blue lines indicate moving from $2^{nd}$ column to $3^{rd}$ column  , Each line is $1$ way.
The total here will be the number of ways from $A$
Initially we are "Diverging" from $A$
We can continue likewise till $B$

Eventually we are "Converging" to $B$
Every time we move right , we have to add up the total from column $n$ to column $n+1$ , like shown by some moves here.
Let us use the table to fill in the numbers there itself.

Hence we have $127$ ways to go from $A$ to $B$
ADDENDUM:
We can not (should not) move to Squares which is not counted/numbered here. That is because those Squares will not let us go from $A$ to reach $B$ within $7$ moves.
More-over , we can not (should not) move backwards.
We will always move forwards.

Problems involving counting the number of possible paths between points given restrictions on what moves can be made can be solved using the adjacency matrix from graph theory.
Given a graph $(V,E)$ with vertices $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, define the adjacency matrix $M$ so that $M_{ij} = 1$ if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent in the graph, otherwise $M_{ij} = 0$.
the number of walks from $v_1$ to $v_n$ of length n is given by $(M^n)_{ij}$, the $(i,j)$-entry of the $n$-th power of the adjacency matrix.  In your case, the vertices correspond to pairs $(x,y)$ with $0 \leq x \leq 7$ and $0 \leq y \leq 7$ and a king can move from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ if the tiles are distinct and $|x_1 - x_2| \leq 1$ and $|y_1 - y_2| \leq 1$. So we could use, e.g., Python, to quickly find the answer:
import numpy as np 

# write down all vertices (ie chessboard tiles) in a list
A = []
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        A.append((x,y))


# form matrix
M = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape = (len(A), len(A))))

for i, (x1,y1) in enumerate(A):
    for j, (x2,y2) in enumerate(A):
        if i != j and np.abs(x1-x2) <= 1 and np.abs(y1-y2) <= 1:
            M[i,j] = 1 

# compute number of walks
start = (0,0)
end = (0, 7)

print((M**7) [A.index(start), A.index(end)]) # prints 127.0

There are various optimizations you could make - for example, in a valid path we note that a king could only move to the right and could not move to the upper half of the board, otherwise it cannot finish. We also don't need to do all $64 \times 64$ comparisons between tiles when checking for adjacency. But in this case it's easy enough to compute directly without these observations. This would also work for any other chess piece (appropriately changing the adjacency condition) or any starting, ending tiles, or any number of steps.
This becomes computationally intensive for large graphs, of course. In that case you can use more specialized methods. If you want the number of ways for a king to move from one corner to an adjacent corner on an $n\times n$ board using $n-1$ steps, see Motzkin numbers.

In this case there are 127 of these 7-step Motzkin paths, see https://oeis.org/A001006 .
